# Program stuck at scanf despite correct code

Tags: c

Each time I run this program it gets stuck at `scanf`, despite using `fflush` -- except that when the input is "2" it works properly.  The compiler does not show any error or warning. I have no clue what is going on, but variable `x` seems somehow to be affecting program, despite being in an `if` block.  When `x` is 1 in the `if` block, the program works as intended, but the loop is infinite.

```
void nonrec_bin(int);

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {            
    int number;            
    printf("Enternumber\n");      
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &number);     
    fflush(stdout);
    nonrec_bin(number);            
    return 0;            
}

void nonrec_bin(int num) {  
    int sum = num, x = 1;
    printf("%d", sum);
    while (x) {    
        if (num == 1) { 
            printf("%d", num);
            num = sum - num;
            x = 0;  
        }
        num /= 2;
    }       
    printf("%d", num);
    for (; num;)
        if (num % 2 == 0 && num / 2 < 2) {
             printf("%d", num);
             num = num / 2;
        }
}
```

Comment: fflush(stdin) isn't correct code. And printf sometimes doesn't actually print until you print a \n

Comment: In general - a correct code is the one that is producing the expected result. Any other code is incorrect.

Comment: Aside:pleasemakeyourcodemorereadablethannum%2==0&&num/2<2, by using a nice amount of whitespace (and punctuation in the first paragraph).

Comment: Do not use use `fflush()` on input. always test the return of `scanf()`. Read the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the issue that is tripping you up is the "for" loop you have within your "nonrec_bin" function.  This statement:

```
for(;num;)
```

will act like an endless loop unless the value of "num" is zero (false), as the second section of a for loop is a "true/false" test.  So in running your code and placing some "printf" statements in to follow what was happening, if any number other than "2" was entered, that "for" loop was effectively an endless loop.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Divisor/bin/Release$ ./Divisor 
Enter number: 2
Initial value is: 2
Calculated value: 1
Value exiting the while loop: 0

@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/Divisor/bin/Release$ ./Divisor 
Enter number: 18
Initial value is: 18
Calculated value: 1
Value exiting the while loop: 8
^C    <---- had to press "Ctrl-C" to break out of the program.
```

So, you might need to reconsider how you are trying to use that "for" loop test.

Answer (score 1):

This loop ...

> ```
>     while(x)
>     {    
>         if(num==1)
>         {   
>             printf("%d",num);
>             num=sum-num;
>             x=0;    
>         }
>         num/=2;
>     }
> ```

... will not terminate if `num` is initially less than 1.  Otherwise, given the initial values of the variables and the fact that `x` is not otherwise used, the whole thing can be replaced by

```
printf("1");
num = num - 1;
```

This loop ...

> ```
>     for (; num; )
>         if(num%2==0&&num/2<2)
>         {
>              printf("%d",num);
>              num=num/2;
>         }
> ```

... iterates until `num` becomes 0, but it modifies `num` or outputs anything only if the condition `num % 2 == 0 && num / 2 < 2` is satisfied.  The only non-negative integers that satisfy that condition are 0 and 2.  Therefore, if `num` is initially 2, the body of the `if` statement is executed exactly once.  That reduces `num` to 1, however, so the loop is infinite unless `num` is initially zero (in which case it produces no output).

Comment: Thank you dear fellow colleagues it helped and sorry for my rude replies i was asking help and people start bashing me. it got me on my nerves indeed it is 'for loop' that is buggy.